# Vue's data items array only work in filter when hardcoded, not when including as a (n echo'ed PHP) Array

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I'm getting weird behaviour and I'm stuck ;/

There's this array I have/use:

```
[
    {
        "Question": "business metrics",
        "Answers": "how well assistant ..."
    },
    {
        "Question": "technical metrics",
        "Answers": "how well is ..."
    },
    {
        "Question": "business metrics types",
        "Answers": "CSAT, coverage ..."
    },
    {
        "Question": "key metrics",
        "Answers": "precision, accuracy ..."
    }
]
```

which is generated by :

```
$json            = json_decode(file_get_contents('assets/feeds/questions.json'), 1);
$flattened_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $json);
$data            = json_encode($flattened_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I include that data in Vue so I can dynamically filter on both Q and A. This only worked for the Q using the following code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        searchValue: '',
        courselines: <?php echo $data ?>        
    },
    computed: {
        filteredCourselines() {
            let tempCourselines = this.courselines;

            // Process search input
            if (!tempCourselines) {
                return [];
            }

            if (this.searchValue !== '' && this.searchValue) {

                return tempCourselines.filter(function (q) {
                    return q.Question.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) >= 0;
                });

            } else {
                return [];
            }

        }
    }
});
```

However, I noticed as soon as I change Questions to Answers, or add it as an or operator, things stop working.

```
return tempCourselines.filter(function (q) {
return q.Answers.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) >= 0 || q.Question.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) >= 0;
});
```

It took me hours to figure out that when I replace the PHP echo by the hardcoded array data, all is just fine.

Here's the matching HTML block:

```
<div id="app" class="m-5">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <input type="text" v-model="searchValue" placeholder="Search Term" class="my-4" id="search-input"></input>
                <div id="courseline-container">
                    <div class="card p-2 m-2" v-for="(courseline, index) in filteredCourselines" :key="index">
                        <div class="content">
                            <span>
                                <p><strong>{{ courseline.Question }}</strong><br/>{{ courseline.Answers }}</p>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I don't understand why, does anybody have a clue?

EDIT:

I found out that the null value in some answers cause the error. I need to know how to run the filter without breaking on null values:

```
[
            {
                "Question": "business metrics",
                "Answers": "how well assistant ..."
            },
            {
                "Question": "technical metrics",
                "Answers": "how well is ..."
            },
            {
                "Question": "business metrics types",
                "Answers": "CSAT, coverage ..."
            },
            {
                "Question": "Scenarios",
                "Answers": null
            },
            {
                "Question": "key metrics",
                "Answers": "precision, accuracy ..."
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Yes, the hardcoded is a direct copy-paste of print_r(). It returns [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')", but only on the PHP echo. Superweird.

Comment: Hold on, I got it. Some answers that were not in my test set have null as the answer. So I need to know how to not throw an error when there's a null value in the set. Added new testset sample to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411705/vues-data-items-array-only-work-in-filter-when-hardcoded-not-when-including-as?noredirect=1#comment122686266_69411705), your actual data set potentially has `null` for some of the `Answers` properties, leading to an error at runtime.

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) to avoid the `null` error:

```js
return tempCourselines.filter(function (q) {
                 
  return q.Answers?.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) >= 0 || q.Question.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) >= 0;
});
```

The first condition returns `undefined` (a falsy value) when `q.Answers` is `undefined` or `null` (indicating that the search value is not found in the possible answers), which then short-circuits to the next condition, checking `q.Question`.